# Lower to Upper Case Conversion with C

Tags: c, arrays, string

### Problem Statement

I'm facing difficulty in solving a programming contest problem, which reads as follows:

> You are given T name(s) in english letters. Each name will include some
>   of the uppercase letters from A to Z, some of the lowercase letters
>   from a to z and some spaces. You have to transform the name(s) from
>   lowercase to uppercase. Letters that are originally uppercase
>   will remain the same and the spaces will also remain in their
>   places.

---

### **Sample Input-Output**

If I type this in...

```
5
Hasnain Heickal    Jami
Mir Wasi Ahmed
Tarif Ezaz
     Mahmud Ridwan
Md    Mahbubul Hasan
```

the computer ***should*** output this...

```
Case 1: HASNAIN HEICKAL    JAMI
Case 2: MIR WASI AHMED
Case 3: TARIF EZAZ
Case 4:      MAHMUD RIDWAN
Case 5: MD    MAHBUBUL HASAN
```

- Note that exactly *one* space is required between the semi-colon and the initial letter of the name.

---

### My Coding

This is what I've coded in ***C***:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    int T, i;
    char string [100];
    scanf("%d", &T);

    for (i=0; i<T; i++) 
    {
        gets(string);
        printf("Case %d: ", i);

        while (string[i])
        {
            putchar (toupper(string[i]));
            i++;
        }          

        printf("\n");
     }  

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Now, this code fails to produce the desired output. Where am I doing it wrong? Is there any matter with my syntax? Can somebody guide me? Please bear in mind that I'm a middle-schooler and just a beginner in C.

Comment: From the help centre: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cycle over each letter of the string one-by-one.

In this code below, I have done that with variable `K`, which goes from 0 to the length of the string.

Variable `I` keeps track of the number of strings.

```
int main(void)
{
  int T, i, k;
  char string [100];

  scanf("%d", &T);

  for ( i = 0; i < T; ++i)
  {
     gets (string);

     for(k=0; k<strlen(string); ++k)
     {
         putchar (toupper(string[k]));
     }
  }  

  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

---

In response your question: [***IDEOne Link***](http://ideone.com/SN6g4s)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  int T, i,k;
  char string [100];

  scanf("%d ", &T);

  for ( i = 0; i < T; ++i)
  {
     gets (string);
     printf("[%d] : %s\n", i, string);

     for(k=0; k<strlen(string); ++k)
     {
         putchar (toupper(string[k]));
     }
     putchar('\n');
  }  

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, thanks!! But, you didn't define "k" variable before applying it into the code.

Comment: I kept the same `gets` function that poster had.   Do you want to confuse a middle-school student with an in-depth discussion of buffer-overflows?  That is ***not*** the topic of the question.

Comment: Can you kindly edit your answer? I have improvised the question.

Comment: Also, using `getch()` requires the "conio.h" header.

Answer (score 2):

Please go through the code and implement the test cases scenarios as per your requirement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
  char string[100];
  int i;
  scanf("%s",string);
  for(i=0;i<strlen(string);i++){
       string[i]=string[i]-32;
  }
  printf("%s",string);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work at all. Anyways, thanks for the answer!!

Comment: Is there any issue with code? Please let us know which test cases it is not working?

Comment: I have run this on my pc and it is working fine, where you are getting the error??

Comment: Put line **#8** within this condition: `if (string[i]>=97 && string[i]<=122)` Cause you only want to change the case if it's lower. Spaces or uppercase letters will turn into some other symbols, which we certainly don't want to happen.